# Error when trying to run monero-wallet-rpc with docker-compose up

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I provide user and password in config file, but I got the error as it tries to create .login file. When I run for the first time it runs without restriction, but when I run for the second time, it throws error.

> docker-compose up        Starting monerodocker_monero_1 ...  Starting
>   monerodocker_monero_1 ... done Attaching to monerodocker_monero_1
>   monero_1  | 2018-04-10 11:18:35.660       7fafb52e0740    INFO
>     global  src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero 'Helium Hydra'
>   (v0.11.1.0-release) monero_1  | Forking to background... monero_1  |
>   Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release) monero_1  | Logging to
>   ./monero-wallet-rpc.log monero_1  | 2018-04-10 11:18:35.674
>   7f4811fef740  ERROR   wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:198    Failed
>   to create file monero-wallet-rpc.18557.login. Check permissions or
>   remove file monero_1  | 2018-04-10 11:18:35.674
>   7f4811fef740  ERROR   wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1894   Failed
>   to initialize wallet rpc server monerodocker_monero_1 exited with code
>   1

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error message when running `monero-wallet-rpc` **without** the option `--disable-rpc-login`.

Then, as explained by **vtnerd** in this [open issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1768):

> The file is always created in the current working directory when
>   authentication is enabled.

To create the file, you need to be the owner of the working directory.

I set the current user within the docker container as the owner of the working directory, so `Check permissions` disappeared and `monero-wallet-rpc` started correctly.

---

By the way:

When leaving `--disable-rpc-login` you should provide `--rpc-login user:password`.